# Значение слова "междоусобица"

Tags: этимология

Задумался над словом "междоусобица" (очень люблю анализировать слова, но лингвистических знаний, увы, не хватает). Интересует вторая часть слова — что она означает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Усобица - от ст.-слав. собица "мятеж".Это слово восходит к глаголу собити – "присваивать", восходящему к основе соб, наблюдаемой в словах особа, собственный.
http://www.onlinedics.ru/slovar/fasmer/u/usobitsa.html
Собственный-заимствование из старославянского, в котором образовано от собъство, имевшему значение "особенность, лицо" от собъ – "существо". К этой же основе восходит и особа. 
http://vseslovari.com.ua/krylov/page/sobstvennyiy.3469/

Междоусобица, получается, процесс обособления, когда каждый воюет за обособленность, независимость от соседей,считает себя главным лицом и хочет присвоить себе то,что раньше считалось общим, - борьба за власть одним словом.

Answer (score 0):

Можете прочитать в  этой ссылке.http://dic.academic.ru/contents.nsf/slovo_o_polku_igoreve/

Answer (score 0):

Усобица  -  в  древнерусском  языке  "мятеж".  См.  Фасмер,  т.4.  Есть  в  тексте  Слова  о  полку  Игореви.